# How to use partition pruning in google big query without hardcoding the filter condition?

Tags: google-bigquery, partitioning, database-partitioning, pruning

I have a big table in GBQ which is partitioned by date. and I want to use partition pruning to optimize my query. the problem is that filter condition is a value that is read from another table and I can't hardcode the value. I wonder if there is any way to use partition pruning in this case and **also I can't use declare statement** because scheduling engine that I am working with doesn't allow that. here is my code:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT tmp.partitionStartDate
  FROM tmp_table tmp
)
SELECT *      
FROM table1  t
WHERE sbcc.partitionDate = (select partitionStartDate from cte)
```

Comment: you should use scripting with `execute immediate` to at a run time partition date will  be defined

Comment: Thanks @MikhailBerlyant, how would you write the above query to use ```execute immediate ``` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
execute immediate "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE partitionDate = ?" using (SELECT partitionStartDate FROM tmp_table);
```

Answer (score 2):

Script below will work:

```sql
DECLARE partitionDate DEFAULT (
  SELECT tmp.partitionStartDate
  FROM tmp_table tmp
);

SELECT *      
FROM table1  t
WHERE sbcc.partitionDate = partitionDate;
```

Or

```sql
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
"""
SELECT *      
FROM table1  t
WHERE sbcc.partitionDate = @partitionDate;
""" USING (
  SELECT tmp.partitionStartDate
  FROM tmp_table tmp
) AS partitionDate;
```

Comment: unfortunately I can't use Declare because of scheduler's constraint that i am using

Comment: understood, added the `execute immediate` approach